# Nagios to monitor network in Cisco packet tracer

Tags: cisco, switch, router, management

I would like to do a network management tool. I need to know how we can use Nagios XI to monitor the network devices that present in the Cisco packet tracer??

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are lots of sites and videos that show you how to configure Nagios.  It's too big a topic to explain here.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

Packet tracert is a closed simulator, which cannot be connected to anything outside of the program.

To do this you can use GNS3 (free - but require real Ciso IOS software images that are not free) or Cisco VIRL (payed) for example. But those require more resources (especially RAM) than Packet Tracer.

Comment: Is it possible to import ios software of one of the old switches? normally we have redundant switches that we do not run now. or should someone purchase ios software without appliance and download it to import to gns3?

Comment: @hakkican it is a bit of a grey area. I'm not sure if there's any official guidance on how to license an IOS image to use in GNS3. I would assume  that if you use an image from a switch you own, it should be ok. You may want to check the GNS3 site, starting from thise page : https://docs.gns3.com/docs/troubleshooting-faq/where-do-i-get-ios-images

Comment: "Physical Cisco devices" section explains it, how can I export ios and import it onto gns3? some of ios images are not supported anymore. does it matter for gns3? What I am trying to do is create an test environment and run some ansible network automation